# Measuring the effect of table compression?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a large MySQL table (>10 million rows) and I'm looking at the best mechanisms to increase query efficiency.

Specifically, table compression looks like it would be beneficial as it would reduce the disk I/O load.

However, how can I go about measuring the impact of using compression? For example, seeing how long a INSERT query takes to execute on the compressed versus non-compressed table?

Comment: Using indexes increases speed significantly.

Comment: @juergend Thanks - I am already using indexes, specifically primary keys

Comment: Indexes and table partitions come to mind before table compression.

Comment: Don't brush juergend aside; indexing is the number one way to improve `SELECT` speed, with or without being I/O bound.  Do you have "composite" indexes that are tailored to the queries?  Show us the slow queries, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We can advise.

Comment: InnoDB compression is likely to give you less than a factor of 2 speedup.  Index changes and/or query rewrites are likely to give you more than 10x in many cases.

Comment: @RickJames thanks -- is it worth also looking at stored procedures? Would these, generally speaking, increase performance?

Comment: SPs won't help.  Your question implies that you know that it is an I/O problem.  At that point, I say "Count the disk hits".  And then I discuss ways of decreasing the number of hits.  [_Cookbook_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) on building optimal index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) for that.

First, while the table are not compresseed yet enable slow log with `long_query_time=0`(you can use [slow.sh](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~akuzminsky/+junk/stats-scripts/view/head:/slow.sh) for convenience).

When you collect a substential amount of queries run `pt-query-digest` on the slow log

```
pt-query-digest slow-query-issue-$issue.log
```

It will give you a queries profile with individual contributions of each query to total response time.

Then compress the tables and repeat the exercise with the `pt-query-digest`.

Then compare two query profile and you will see the compression impact.